# How can I fix and optimize this very simple piece of "Game of Life" code by taking advantage of NumPy's functionality?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matplotlib, vectorization

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from random import randint

arraySize = 50
Z = np.array([[randint(0, 1) for x in range(arraySize)] for y in range(arraySize)])


def computeNeighbours(Z):
    rows, cols = len(Z), len(Z[0])
    N = np.zeros(np.shape(Z))

    for x in range(rows):
        for y in range(cols):
            Q = [q for q in [x-1, x, x+1] if ((q >= 0) and (q < cols))]
            R = [r for r in [y-1, y, y+1] if ((r >= 0) and (r < rows))]
            S = [Z[q][r] for q in Q for r in R if (q, r) != (x, y)]
            N[x][y] = sum(S)

    return N

def iterate(Z):
    rows, cols = len(Z), len(Z[0])
    N = computeNeighbours(Z)

    for x in range(rows):
        for y in range(cols):
            if Z[x][y] == 1:
                if (N[x][y] < 2) or (N[x][y] > 3):
                    Z[x][y] = 0
            else:
                if (N[x][y] == 3):
                    Z[x][y] = 1

    return Z

fig = plt.figure()

Zs = [Z]
ims = []

for i in range(0, 100):
    im = plt.imshow(Zs[len(Zs)-1], interpolation = 'nearest', cmap='binary')
    ims.append([im])
    Zs.append(iterate(Z))

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=250, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

At first, I wrote a simple implementation of ["Game of Life"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) using nothing but standard Python tools. I plotted it, it ran correctly, and it animated correctly.

I tried converting the arrays into NumPy arrays next, which is where the code is as it stands right now. **However, the animation no longer seems to work, and I haven't been able to figure out why.** (**Update:** this bug has been fixed!)

Next, I am interested in taking advantage of NumPy in order to optimize my code. What I have done so far is convert the Python arrays I was using into NumPy arrays. While I am sure there is some gain in performance, it is not recognizable.

**I am interested in knowing what sequence of optimizations one would perform for this sort of an application**, so that I can get a handle on how to use NumPy's power for my current project, which is  simply a (perhaps) three dimensional, cellular automaton with many rules.

---

The following changes to the code fixed the animation error:

1) Change `iterate` to create a deep copy of Z, and then make changes to that deep copy. The new `iterate`:

```
def iterate(Z):
    Zprime = Z.copy()
    rows, cols = len(Zprime), len(Zprime[0])
    N = computeNeighbours(Zprime)

    for x in range(rows):
        for y in range(cols):
            if Zprime[x][y] == 1:
                if (N[x][y] < 2) or (N[x][y] > 3):
                    Zprime[x][y] = 0
            else:
                if (N[x][y] == 3):
                    Zprime[x][y] = 1

    return Zprime
```

2) As a consequence of 1, change this piece of code:

```
for i in range(0, 100):
    im = plt.imshow(Zs[len(Zs)-1], interpolation = 'nearest', cmap='binary')
    ims.append([im])
    Zs.append(iterate(Z))
```

to:

```
for i in range(0, 100):
    im = plt.imshow(Zs[len(Zs)-1], interpolation = 'nearest', cmap='binary')
    ims.append([im])
    Zs.append(iterate(Zs[len(Zs)-1]))
```

Comment: Right off the bat, I can recommend 1) not using `import *`, and 2) including the code in the question instead of linking it.

Comment: @user2357112 I have edited the post as you recommended!

Comment: Why do you have a list of `Zs`? `iterate` mutates the original instead of creating a copy, so the list only contains references to a single array. Even if `iterate` made a new array, you only ever use the most recent `Z` state.

Comment: I suspect changing `iterate` to make a new array may fix your bug. I'm not sufficiently familiar with matplotlib to be sure, but it may be that now that you're passing arrays to matplotlib, the library is simply saving references to your arrays instead of making new arrays out of your data.

Comment: @user2357112 When I change `iterate` to make a copy of `Z`, the animation now proceeds with one more step. (I have updated the code my post to reflect the change I made)

Comment: Don't edit the question to improve the code; it creates a moving target for answerers and makes understanding the answers confusing for anyone who comes by later.

Comment: @user2357112 Got it, I won't edit the code! I have fixed the animation bug though, with your help, so that's good!

Comment: This would be a good http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ question.

Comment: True. Now that the animation bug is fixed, the question is straight code review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following:

```
for x in range(rows):
        for y in range(cols):
            if Z[x][y] == 1:
                if (N[x][y] < 2) or (N[x][y] > 3):
                    Z[x][y] = 0
            else:
                if (N[x][y] == 3):
                    Z[x][y] = 1
```

could be replaced by:

```
set_zero_idxs = (Z==1) & ((N<2) | (N>3))
set_one_idxs = (Z!=1) & (N==3)
Z[set_zero_idxs] = 0
Z[set_one_idxs] = 1
```

This will take more operations than the loop that you have, but I would expect it to be faster.

EDIT:

So I have just benchmarked the two solutions, somewhat unsurprisingly the numpy version is 180 times faster:

```
In [49]: %timeit no_loop(z,n)
1000 loops, best of 3: 177 us per loop

In [50]: %timeit loop(z,n)
10 loops, best of 3: 31.2 ms per loop
```

EDIT2:

I think that this loop:

```
for x in range(rows):
        for y in range(cols):
            Q = [q for q in [x-1, x, x+1] if ((q >= 0) and (q < cols))]
            R = [r for r in [y-1, y, y+1] if ((r >= 0) and (r < rows))]
            S = [Z[q][r] for q in Q for r in R if (q, r) != (x, y)]
            N[x][y] = sum(S)
```

can be replaced by:

```
N = np.roll(Z,1,axis=1) + np.roll(Z,-1,axis=1) + np.roll(Z,1,axis=0) + np.roll(Z,-1,axis=0)
```

Here there is an implicit assumption that the array does not have bounds and that `x[-1]` is next to `x[0]`. If this is a problem, you could add a buffer of zeros around your array with:

```
shape = Z.shape
new_shape = (shape[0]+2,shape[1]+2)
b_z = np.zeros(new_shape)
b_z[1:-1,1:-1] = Z
b_n = np.roll(b_z,1,axis=1) + np.roll(b_z,-1,axis=1) + np.roll(b_z,1,axis=0) + np.roll(b_z,-1,axis=0)
N = b_n[1:-1,1:-1]
```

And for a benchmark:

```
In [4]: %timeit computeNeighbours(z)
10 loops, best of 3: 140 ms per loop 

In [5]: %timeit noloop_computeNeighbours(z)
10000 loops, best of 3: 133 us per loop

In [6]: %timeit noloop_with_buffer_computeNeighbours(z)
10000 loops, best of 3: 170 us per loop
```

So just a small improvement of a factor of **1052**. Hooray for Numpy!

Comment: Careful there - the computation of `set_one_idxs` sees the effects of the first change. It doesn't happen to cause a bug here, but it'd still be better to compute both sets of indices before modifying `Z`. (With the code changed to operate on a copy of `Z`, the bug potential also diminishes.)

Comment: You don't need to call `where`; you can use the mask generated by `(Z==1) & ((N<2) | (N>3))` to index `Z` for the same effect.

Comment: I never quite appreciated how much more performant is to just create boolean arrays than to do a `np.where`. I have updated the benchmark I posted to reflect the code with the change.

Comment: cant the compute_neighbours be sped up a lot too by getting rid of the python forloops?

Comment: Yup, undoubtedly. I haven't had a go at that bit yet.

Comment: Had a go at that bit too and there is some speedup to be gained.

Comment: @ebarr Also, what about this: using A[x,y] instead of A[x][y] in order to avoid transient sub-copies of arrays? I found a reference speaking about this, but I can't find it right now...

Comment: @user89 I think that is only a problem if you are using fancy indexing for x and y. Either way, the solution I posted does not use indexing of Z or N, so should suffer none of those problems.