# Cellular automata on a hexagonal grid?

Tags: python

[I have been playing around with simple cellular automata in Python on a square grid, using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22802708/how-can-i-fix-and-optimize-this-very-simple-piece-of-game-of-life-code-by-taki).

[Which Python based tools would be most useful in helping me work with cellular automata on hexagonal grids?](http://www.collidoscope.com/ca/hcat.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is not clear and sufficiently detailed as it is. Please rephrase, add code, add explanations, etc or you will be downvoted (not a threat, simply a concern)

Comment: @sshashank124 What's not clear about it, and what further detail would you require? I have added some links to the question, in an effort to provide some more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to represent the grid as a hextile. Please look at this post which discusses how to represent a hexagonal grid in memory: [How do I represent a hextile/hex grid in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1838656/3248346)